# How to avoid acoustic feedback while fixing radios?

Tags: repair

CQ CQ CQ de BH4FHO.

I have been fixing some radios recently - buying used radios for cheap, fix them up and modify them to transmit in ham bands. When testing them out, I am using my Baofeng DM-1801 HT (with OpenGD77 firmware) as a test target - tune the Baofeng to the same test channel as the DUT radio, and try to call each other.

However, whenever I press the PTT button on either radio, there is is a chance for some very loud acoustic feedback hitting my head with a screech. How to avoid that?

Comment: Hello Maxthon, and welcome to ham.stackexchange.com!

Answer (score 5):

You could use a headset or earphones with the receiving radio, so the received audio goes straight into your ears instead of to the microphone of the transmitting radio.  Or you could use an assistant to take one radio to another room for your communications tests.

Comment: Turning the volume down on the receiving radio may also help.